# Android login with community custom domain redirect to out of app

Tags: mobilesdk

Im using salesforce SDK to create android app . When i login app with the default community domain everything work fine . But when i change to use the custom community domain , it will redirect out of the app . It'll open the webview or browser on device . Is there way to keep it stay in app when use custom community domain ? Thank .